# Schema input type always "LinkedHashMap cannot be cast..."

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql-java

My schema.grapqls looks like...

```
scalar BigDecimal
...
input TemplateLineItemInput {
    partMasterId: String!
    partMasterIdPath: String!
    actionType: String!
    actionQuantity: BigDecimal!
}
...
type Mutation {
    ...
    createLineItem(id: ID! input: TemplateLineItemInput!): TemplateBom
}
```

My POJOs are all Lombok-ie and were working great until I tried to create that `input`.

```
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

@Data
@Builder
public class TemplateLineItemInput {
  private final String partMasterId;
  private final String partMasterIdPath;
  private final String actionType;
  private final BigDecimal actionQuantity;
}
```

I believe I have the mutation it wired up correctly...

```
@Component
public class TemplateBomDataWiring  implements RuntimeWiringBuilderCustomizer {
  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TemplateBomDataWiring.class);

  private final TemplateBomService templateBomService;

  public TemplateBomDataWiring(TemplateBomService templateBomService) {
    this.templateBomService = templateBomService;
  }

  @Override
  public void customize(RuntimeWiring.Builder builder) {
    builder.scalar(Scalars.GraphQLBigDecimal);
    builder.scalar(GraphQLDate);
    builder.type("Query", typeWiring -> typeWiring.dataFetcher("templateBom", env -> {
      final String id = env.getArgument("id");
      return templateBomService.getTemplateBom(id);
    }));
    builder.type("Mutation", typeWiring -> typeWiring.dataFetcher("create", env -> {
      final String partMasterId = env.getArgument("partMasterId");
      return templateBomService.createTemplateBom(partMasterId);
    }));
    builder.type("Mutation", typeWiring -> typeWiring.dataFetcher("createLineItem", env -> {
      final String id = env.getArgument("id");
      final TemplateLineItemInput input = env.getArgument("input");
      return templateBomService.createTemplateLineItem(id, input);
    }));
  }
```

But I can't get the query to parse in GraphiQL. I get no stacktrace server side, I just get this in the GraphiQL UI...

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "class java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to class com.example.boa.domain.TemplateLineItemInput (java.util.LinkedHashMap is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; com.example.boa.domain.TemplateLineItemInput is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader @617a9621)",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 42,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "createLineItem"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "classification": "INTERNAL_ERROR"
      }
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "createLineItem": null
  }
}
```

I'm working pretty much off the https://www.graphql-java.com/documentation/v16/ docs

How do I get my `input` type to map into the TemplateLineItemInput POJO on graphql-java:16.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use spring boot to automatically define your runtime wiring.
And you can write query fetchers or mutation fetchers by implementing

```
GraphQLQueryResolver
GraphQLMutationResolver
```

If you are doing the runtime wiring, the complex input parameters other than basic types will always be passed as key, value pairs in a LinkedHashmap.
So you have to convert the passed linkedHashmap into the class you expect as below.

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            String input = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(env.getArgument("input"));
            final String arg = env.getArgument("input");
            return templateBomService.createTemplateLineItem(id, objectMapper.readValue(arg,TemplateLineItemInput.class));
```

Comment: There is no GraphQLQueryResolver or GraphQLMutationResolver at graphql-java 16.2. I was under the impression _I had_ to do customize DataWiring to get the stuff to map. I think this question becomes, at 16.2, what is the replacement for GraphQLQueryResolver and GraphQLMutationResolver. I am familiar with those and they did to the automagic type resolution.

I think I'm working to hard here.

Comment: Yeah. This works but, yuk. I gotta get those graphql-java-tools in or something to get out of that DataWiring and into something more automapping. I'm working off Spring's https://docs.spring.io/spring-graphql/docs/1.0.0-M1/reference/html/#boot-graphql and it looks to be very incomplete. They are trying to get to some annotations based thing but they aren't there yet.

In any event, thanks for the clue. I'm unblocked.